# How to compare between object elments values in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, compare

How to compare between object elments values in javascript

For example :

```
var obj = { tom: "5000", justin: "500", linda: "3000" };
```

How I can make a code to know which person have the higher salary as in the example: I should get as a result here (tom)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get first all keys of the object with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then reduce by getting the higher salary key with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var object = { tom: "5000", justin: "500", linda: "3000" },
    keys = Object.keys(object),
    max = keys.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return +object[a] > +object[b] ? a : b;
    });

console.log(max);
```

For getting more than only one top key, you need a different approach and return an array instead of a single value.

```js
var object = { justin: "500", linda: "3000",  tom: "5000", jane: "5000" },
    keys = Object.keys(object),
    max = keys.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i || +object[a] > +object[r[0]]) {
            return [a];
        }
        if (+object[a] === +object[r[0]]) {
            r.push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(max);
```

Comment: This will compare strings, not numbers. If my `object` would be something like `{ tom: "5000", justin: "500", linda: "3000", tim: "10000" }`, it will produce an incorrect result. I suggest adding `parseInt()` to get a number from a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMaxUser(object) {
    let maxUser = { max: 0 }
    for (let user in object) {
        if (maxUser.max < object[user]) {
            maxUser = {
                max: object[user],
                user: user
            }
        }
    }
    return maxUser
}
var obj = { tom: "5000", justin: "500", linda: "3000" }
console.log(getMaxUser(object).user)  //tom
```